# Unity 3D - Multiple targets not working

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, target

I'm making an application in Unity 3D for Android which consists in detect a pattern with the phone camera and then it appears a plane (that acts like a button) that starts a video if you click it.

So, I've 4 different Image Targets with 4 different patterns and inside every Image Target it is a plane that appears when the pattern is detected. When you touch the plane it executes the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PlayVideo1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string moviePath = "video1.mp4";
    void Update () {
        // Code for OnMouseDown in the iPhone. Unquote to test.
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase.Equals(TouchPhase.Began)) {
                Debug.Log("Starting Movie: " + moviePath);  
                Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie (moviePath, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full);
                Debug.Log("All Done!"); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every plane has a different script with a different moviePath, for example:

The plane 1 has the PlayVideo1.cs with the moviePath "video1.mp4".
The plane 2 has the PlayVideo2.cs with the moviePath "video2.mp4".
The plane 3 has the PlayVideo3.cs with the moviePath "video3.mp4".
The plane 4 has the PlayVideo4.cs with the moviePath "video4.mp4".

Then when I detect one of the 4 patters with the camera and the button appears when I click it always plays the same video ("video3.mp4" for example) even if the pattern I'm focusing with the camera is the one with the plane 1 or 2.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your code does not check which plane is being clicked. What it is currently doing is just detecting whether there is any touch input.

Change your code to the below

```
//On MouseUpAsButton is a Monobehaviour event that is called on every collider 
//where the interaction is like a button (i.e. click down and release on the same collider)
public void OnMouseUpAsButton () {
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie (moviePath, Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full);
}
```

Also note that if you're using Unity 4.6 and above, you MUST have the **Event System** component attached to SOME GameObject in your scene, otherwise **OnMouseUpAsButton** will not get called.

Finally, there are a lot of other useful events that Monobehvaiour has, including **OnMouseEnter**, **OnMouseDown**, **OnMouseExit**, **OnMouseUp** etc. [Link to Monobehaviour in Unity's Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)

P.S. **Mouse** events do work on mobile, so you can safely use it.